# To get nodes from a subgraph that are connected to a particular node

Tags: database, neo4j, graphql, cypher, neo4j-apoc

To explain the problem i have to optimize a cypher query where i am getting nodes connected to a particular node after the subgraph is formed

**The query looks like -**

```
match (node{property}) 
apoc.call.subgraphnodes(
        rel filter (has_X,is_y),
         label filter (+x|/y|>z)) 
match (z)-[is_y]-(y) 
return collect(z.id)
```

**Problem statement:**
Question 1. Is there any way to avoid match statement so that the number of db hits can be reduced

Question 2. Is there a possibility in which i return relationships using subgraphAll and apply filter on a list of relationships like TYPE(relationships) = "is_y"

Comment: You might want to add index on node and relationships

Comment: pls give us sample data and examples to simulate your question(s). thanks.